# iOS: Change constraints in edit mode

Tags: ios, constraints

I have a table view with a textfield on the left hand side of a cell and on the right hand side there is a label.

The constraints of the label are very fixed, with a fixed width, vertical center of the container and fixed distance to the right edge of the container.

The constraints of the textfield are variable. It has a fixed position to the left side of the container, also vertical center of the container and a fixed distance to the right edge of the container. But since no width is set, the width is actually variable, depending on the device my app is used.

Now, in edit mode I hide the label and only show the textfield. So I would like to decrease the spacing of the textfield to the right end of the container since no label is in the way. But how can I do this in code? All constraints are set in XCode and I have no experience in doing this with code...

Edit: Screenshot
[image]

Comment: An screenshot of this would be helpful.

Comment: Are you subclassing UITableView? Take a look at - (void)layoutSubviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could setup an IBOutlet from your right (Trailing) constraint to your UITableViewCell. Then, in your UITableViewCell, change the constant of the right (Trailing) constraint.

Ex.

```
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *textFieldTrailingSpaceToViewConstraint;

    [self layoutIfNeeded];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^
    {
        [textFieldTrailingSpaceToViewConstraint setConstant: 100];

        [self layoutIfNeeded];

    } completion:nil];
```

Comment: That seems what I'm looking for but I still have some questions. First of all I didn't know you can make an outlet of a constraint, that's very cool :-) But what I don't understand the constraint is in a table view cell. If I try to outlet from the cell, this doesn't work because self.view setneedsLayout doesn't work then. Can I make this outlet from the cell to the viewcontroller and this works then for all cells?

Comment: I apologize, I was trying to do this from memory. It's actually layoutIfNeeded not setNeedsLayout.

Comment: Your code doesn't work...for UIView I don't get this method animationwithduration...

Comment: I've updated my code with the correct class method. It's actually animateWithDuration:. The above code should work as expected.

Comment: Tried again, made a mistake myself. It really works perfectly. Thx alot!!